# ffmpeg to convert mov to flv

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a mov video to flv, but keep getting these errors below.
There are 2 commands I used, both are below.

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -deinterlace -acodec copy -r 25 -qmin 3 -qmax 6 video.flv


FFmpeg version SVN-r16573, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
configuration: --extra-cflags=-fno-common --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthreads --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-libx264 --enable-libschroedinger --enable-avisynth --enable-swscale --enable-gpl
libavutil     49.12. 0 / 49.12. 0
libavcodec    52.10. 0 / 52.10. 0
libavformat   52.23. 1 / 52.23. 1
libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
libswscale     0. 6. 1 /  0. 6. 1
built on Jan 13 2009 02:57:09, gcc: 4.2.4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid\video.mov':
Duration: 00:03:16.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 398 kb/s
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 800x600 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30.00 tb(r)
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Output #0, flv, to 'vid\video.flv':
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: flv, yuv420p, 800x600 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=3-6, 200 kb/s, 25.00 tb(c)
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
[NULL @ 0x1714390]codec not compatible with flv
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)
```

Second command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -deinterlace -ar 44100 -r 25 -qmin 3 -qmax 6 video.flv
```

Audio resampler only works with 16 bits per sample, patch welcome.

With a newer version of ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version N-49610-gc2dd5a1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Feb  5 2013 13:20:59 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 17.101 / 52. 17.101
  libavcodec     54. 91.100 / 54. 91.100
  libavformat    54. 61.104 / 54. 61.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 35.101 /  3. 35.101
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid\video.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  Duration: 00:02:50.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 370 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1366x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 683:384], 308 kb/s, 11.50 fps, 11.50 tbr, 23 tbn, 23 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : DataHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_u8 (raw  / 0x20776172), 8000 Hz, mono, u8, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : DataHandler
[flv @ 026347a0] FLV does not support sample rate 8000, choose from (44100, 22050, 11025)
Output #0, flv, to 'vid\video.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf54.61.104
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: flv1 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 1366x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 683:384], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 11.50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : DataHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 8000 Hz, mono, s16p
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : DataHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 -> flv)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 -> libmp3lame)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
```

1 more thing please:
If I use this newer version of ffmpeg to create a video with the below command, I get a video with a very hazy display.
It's like a few black dots on a blank screen:

```
ffmpeg -i img%d.png -i audio.wav -acodec copy output.mov
```

what could be the reason for this display?

Comment: `FFmpeg version SVN-r16573`. Use something that is not ancient. There have been at least 33096 updates to FFmpeg since your version. Development is very active and usage of something so old is a waste of time for you and for us.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how to compile an exe with the latest ffmpeg download? I got visual c++ here on my pc. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to compile? See [Zeranoe FFmpeg builds for Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: Hi, I used that too, but it gives the same error. Another problem with Zeranoe's built was that when I used it to make a video using "png" images img%d.png, the display was all shattered, nothing visible, just dots. This is why I went back to an older version that made the video properly.

Comment: Can you try: `ffmpeg -i img%d.png -i audio.wav output.flv`

Comment: Hi, could you please post this command as an answer, so I can accept this? This one worked with the newer version of ffmpeg. Thanks

Comment: Going back to ancient versions is not recommended and are unsupported. For future reference whenever you encounter issues you need to include the command and the complete console output for each issue.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the the simple:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov video.flv
```

In the first command the audio codec is `pcm_u8` and is not compatible with `flv`. Since you have used `-acodec copy`, it results in an error. In the second command , the resampling is causing an issue.

Comment: I doubt the resampling message will appear with a ffmpeg version that is not ~4 years old.

Comment: Hi, if I use the simple command, I get the same error: could not write to header, as in first command. Thanks

Comment: Can you install the latest version of ffmpeg? The version you have is very old. This will most probably fix your issue.

Comment: Hi, I tried with the latest version too, but I get the same error "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input". The mov is also made using ffmpeg itself with img%d.png files.

Comment: Did you add audio stream to the mov? Can you use aac instead of pcm_u8, when you generate mov? Also, you can generate flv instead of mov in the first place?

Comment: Can you update the question with the respons you got from the latest version?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with response of a newer version of ffmpeg. thanks